# Find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of A

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

scale by 2 in the x direction, then scale by 2 in the y direction, then projection onto the line y = x

Comment: What do you mean by 'geometrically'?

Comment: Or just ignore this for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. To find fhe eigenvalues compute the solutions of $\det(xI-A)=0$ i.e. $$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc} x-1 & -1 \\
-1 & x-1 \end{array}\right)=(x-1)^2-1$$ from this the solutions are $x=0$ and $x=2$.
For the eigenvector solve the systems 
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\
y \end{array}\right)=2\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\
y \end{array}\right)$$ and change $2$ by $0$ for the other case.

Comment: Solving this you found that the space of eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $2$ are all $(x,y)$ of the form $(x,x)$. Similary for the $0$ all pairs of the form $(x,-x)$

Comment: Thanks, I understand. What about the right hand side of the equation, what should i do to those 3 matrices

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather represent it as a product of two operators: the projection onto line y=x and the scaling by 2 in both directions.

One eigenvalue 0 and the corresponding eigenvector (1,-1) is due to projection for geometric reason: all the vectors normal to the projection target subspace vanish.

The other eigenvalue 2 and the corresponding eigenvector (1,1) is due to a combination of two facts: the projection is identity on the target subspace and the scaling multiplies the vectors of that subspace by the scaling factor.